# animate the textfield to top when it is clicked to type a text from keypad

Tags: ios, uitextfield, animated

I am new to iOS, just started to design an login form. when user click the textfield, keypad appears which hide the textfield so I unable to see the textfield.
 So how I animate the textfield to top at the time of keypad appear.

Comment: There are some hints in proposed duplicate, but it doesn't seem to solve this exact problem, of course that may just be because this problem is insufficiently detailed.  Are you wanting the whole view to slide up?  Wanting it to be scrollable?  Wanting just the text field to slide up?  What about the password field?

Comment: ya David what you said is right. i want the particular textfield to slide up when the textfield is clicked.. i don't want to slide up the whole view..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this->

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == ChatField)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    }return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == ChatField) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
    }return YES;
}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    float newVerticalPosition = -keyboardSize.height + 10;

    [self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:newVerticalPosition forDuration:0.3f];
}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGFloat  kNavBarHeight =  self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    float newVerticalPosition = kNavBarHeight  -45;

    [self moveFrameToVerticalPosition:newVerticalPosition forDuration:0.3f];

}


- (void)moveFrameToVerticalPosition:(float)position forDuration:(float)duration {
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    frame.origin.y = position;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        self.view.frame = frame;
    }];
}
```